# Getting value from another form in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, radio-button

So I have these two forms: Form1 and Form2. The first form has a groupbox with radio buttons in it that selects a dormitory with values. At the bottom of the page is a button that says continue and goes to Form 2. In Form2 there is another button that has a groupbox with radios to select a meal plan. At the bottom of the page there is a button that says calculate. When this button is clicked Form1 should show again and there textbox for total cost will have a value in it for the dormcost and mealcost. It works for getting the meal cost, but not the dorm.

Anybody have any idea why?

Form 1:

```
Public Class Form1

Public DormCost As Integer

Private Sub ButtonCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalculate.Click

    Dim DormCost As Integer

    If RadioAllen.Checked = True Then
        DormCost = 1500
    ElseIf RadioPike.Checked = True Then
        DormCost = 1600
    ElseIf RadioFarthing.Checked = True Then
        DormCost = 1200
    ElseIf RadioUniversity.Checked = True Then
        DormCost = 1800
    End If

    Form2.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Form 2:

```
Public Class Form2

Dim MealCost As Integer
Dim Total As String


Private Sub ButtonCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalculate.Click


    If Radio7.Checked = True Then
        MealCost = 560
    ElseIf Radio14.Checked = True Then
        MealCost = 1095
    ElseIf RadioUnlimited.Checked = True Then
        MealCost = 1500
    End If

    Me.Close()

    Total = Convert.ToString(Form1.DormCost + MealCost)
    Form1.TextBox1.Text = "$" + Total


End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option:

Make `DormCost` local to form1 and call it say `myDormCost` and put it as Public to Form2
then when you call

```
form2.show
```

right before that do

```
form2.DormCost = myDormCost
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a global variable class, which can be used all throughout your program.

`Public Class GlobalVariables`

```
Public Shared yourvariable As yourtype
```

`End Class`

Put this class at the bottom of one of your forms and you can call the variable form anywhere in the program. `GlobalVariables.yourvariable`

Comment: While that would solve this exact problem, it's generally a bad idea to do so. It creates hidden dependencies between the forms and hard to track interactions between objects. Given that forms are just objecs, the best way is to add properties or methods and call them using references.